# Socket.Io Differents "disconnect" reason on different browsers

Tags: socket.io

I'm tring to use Socket.io 4.4.0 library in Javascript for a game project.

I think, after some tests, that server side is good.

But I have any problems on differents mobile environments:
I need to reconnect the client after connection lost (ex. Wi-Fi to mobile data or viceversa)
or after wake up after smartphone inactivity (smartphone in stand-by).

If I work in Android with Chrome or Firefox, no issue, the socket reconnects.
If I work in Safari, client can't reconnect because seems that "reason" is differents respectly other browsers.

Is there anyone who had the same problem as me and can suggest me some strategy to solve it?

Thanks you a lots!

--
OHF

Comment: could you please rephrase 'because seems that "reason" is differents respectly other browsers' ? i do not get it...

Comment: Hello fwiw, as you can see here : https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-socket-instance/#disconnect when client disconnect will trigger event "disconnect" with a reason. In Android with Chrome if smartphone goes in stand-by mode reason is "transport close" so, when wake up the socket retry to reconnect. In iOS using Safari reason is "io client disconnect".